# Why is "display:none" still taking up space?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a specific cell in a table disappear while viewing the HTML page on mobile  and have a width of 20% while on PC, but when I view this on my mobile, the table cell is invisible **but still takes up space**. I have found multiple people online saying that display:none isn't meant to take up space, but I can't seem to get that result.

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .mobileHide {display: inline; width : 20%;}
    
  @media only screen
  and (min-device-width : 320px)
  and (max-device-width : 480px){
    .mobileHide {
      display : none;
      width : 1% !important;
      overflow : hidden;
    }
  }
</style>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <div class="mobileHide">
        <td>
          This cell is meant to be 20% wide on PC but non-existent on mobile.
        </td>
      </div>
      <td>
        This cell is meant to be 60% wide on PC and 100% wide on mobile.
      </td>
      <div class="mobileHide">
        <td>
          This cell is meant to be 20% wide on PC but non-existent on mobile.
        </td>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If anyone is able to help me with this, that would be great.

Comment: your html is invalid .you cannot have div directly inside tr only td allowed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your markup is invalid. A block element like `<div>` cannot be a child of `<tr>`; the only valid elements in this context are `<td>` and `<th>`.

In Google Chrome, this markup is reinterpreted to place the `<div>` elements at the root of the document body, e.g.

```
<div class="mobileHide"></div>
<div class="mobileHide"></div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      This cell is meant to be 20% wide on PC but non-existent on mobile.
    </td>
    <td>
      This cell is meant to be 60% wide on PC and 100% wide on mobile.
    </td>
    <td>
      This cell is meant to be 20% wide on PC but non-existent on mobile.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to hide table cells on mobile devices, apply the `mobileHide` class directly to the table cells.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have applied the class to the table cell directly and it it causing the cell to act as if it is non-existent on both PC & Mobile. Although knowing this has given me a few more possibilities to troubleshoot the issue.